# How to add zip file without compression using node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am converting docx to epub using pandoc.  After converting epub, i do changes with zip file and converting epub also. At that time,

I got the following issue after converting zip file to epub on mimetype file.

```
 Mimetype contains wrong type (application/epub+zip expected).
```

I am searching a lot and get two logic

1. First one e.g., extra spaces, new line characters but it was going vain(there is no extra spaces, new line).
2. Add the mimetype file without compression in zip.

I am getting struck with second point.  How to add mimetype file without compression in zip using node.js coding.

```
 var archiver = require('archiver');
 var archive = archiver('zip');
 archive.file('d:\\xxxx'+'\\mimetype', { name:'mimetype'});
```

What is the problem in the above code and any attribute for zip?

Can any one assist me for adding file without compression in zip?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do it like  this :archive.file('dir_location/filename.txt', { name:'filename.txt' });

Comment: Same as : archive.file('d:\\xxxx'+'\\mimetype.,txt', { name:'mimetype.txt'});  Nothing different..   How to mention compress method in this above code?

Comment: can you print , console.log(d:\\xxxx'+'\\mimetype)?let me know that

Comment: @PPB:  I got solution. thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the zip option {store:true} for without compression
https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver#store-boolean